# Rails 4; Raise an error and catch within controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd love to define a `rescue_from` handler in my controller to respond to the error.

```
modudle Api
  module V1
    class TreesController < Api::V1::ApiController
      rescue_from TreeNotFound, with: :missing_tree

       def show
         @tree = find_tree
        end

       private

       def missing_tree(error)
         redirect_to(action: :index, flash: error.message)
        end

       def find_tree
         find_forest.trees.find(params[:id])
       rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
         raise TreeNotFound, "Couldn't find a tree to hug"
       end
     end
   end
end
```

However I got some error `Api::V1::TreesController::TreeNotFound`.

Any idea?

#### Update

```
    # api_controller.rb    
    module Api
      module V1
        class ApiController < JSONAPI::ResourceController
          skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token # Disable CSRF to enable to function as API

          respond_to :json

          # NOTE: This block is used when you put unrelated values
          rescue_from(ArgumentError) do |e|
            render json: { error: e.message }, states: 400 # :bad_request
          end

          rescue_from(ActionController::ParameterMissing) do |e|
            error = {}
            error[e.param] = ['parameter is required']
            response = { errors: [error] }
            render json: response, status: 422 # :unprocessable_entity
          end   
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Do you have any code in `ApiController` that can raise this error? As example you try find `current_user`

Comment: `AccountNotFound` does that mean anything in your app?  Do you inherit `TreeNotFound` from that but forgot to declare it?

Comment: @jvnill I'm sorry that is actually `Api::V1::TreesController::TreeNotFound`. Not `AccountNotFound`

Comment: ah then you just need to declare that. inherit from `StandardError`. `class Api::V1::TreesController::TreeNotFound < StandardError; end`

Comment: @jvnill yeah I actually I already figured out xd. However thanks!

Comment: You can write the same answer below, and will pick this as the one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to declare the error class first before you can use it.  Do this by inheriting from `StandardError`.

```
class TreeNotFound < StandardError
end
```